# php, how to pack int to signed 64bit little-endian string?

Tags: php, integer, endianness, pack

Strangely seems pack() doesn't support *signed* 64bit little-endian, while it support unsigned, so how do I pack a signed one?

For reference, if I want an unsigned 64bit little-endian pack(), i would simply do

```php
    $packed = pack("P", $i);
```

Answer (score 1):

From php official docs [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

> Note that the distinction between signed and unsigned values only
> affects the function unpack(), where as function pack() gives the same
> result for signed and unsigned format codes.